# Unable to use jquery in my mvc .net project

Tags: jquery, .net, model-view-controller

I've just started working with ASP.Net MVC4 project. I want to work with jQuery for click events in my project, but I am unable to get success even when I included jQuery in my layout.cshtml and Index(home) pages as follows,

Index(home):

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

 $("#searchId").click(function () {
        alert("Serach was clicked.");
    });
```

Layout.cshtml:

```
<body>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

  <p><input type="button" value="search" id="searchId" /></p>
</body>
```

Can anybody help me please to get a solution?

Comment: Check with Firefox (Firebug) or Chrome (Developer Tools) in Network tab if jQuery is loaded?

Answer (score 2):

Your DOM might not be ready when you are registering the event handlers, try encapsulating the event handlers in document ready like this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchId").click(function () {
        alert("Serach was clicked.");
    });
 });
```

Also I don't see the @RenderBody() method being called in your layout, that might give you an error too.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is, you are rendering Jquery bundle 2 times both in Index and Layout page.

As Layout.cshtml is a master page so you have to put Jquery bundle only in master page not in the child index page.

And in the child index page just use following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#searchId").click(function () {
    alert("Serach was clicked.");
   });
 });
```

or

```
$( "#searchId" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert("Serach was clicked.");
});
```

Let me know if you still have the problem.